# Listview running sample - setLocal error

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to run the sample at [NS Listview sample](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view)

I'm getting a compile time error on

`onSetupItemView(args: SetupItemViewArgs) {
      args.view.setLocal('third', (args.index % 3 === 0));
  }`

Getting an error: Property 'setLocal' does not exist on type 'EmbeddedViewRef'

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `EmbeddedViewRef.setLocal()` is deprecated.

Now it's `args.view.context.third = new_value;`